# How many certificates are necessary for a secure Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to wrap my brain around how many certificates I'm going to need for service fabric. I've read quite a bit from the product team and that's been really helpful, now I'm trying to distill that down to what I actually need given the following goals:

1. Create a secure cluster with AAD authentication (I'm good with the AAD part)
2. Enable communication over HTTPS/SSL for self-hosted web api that will reside on the cluster
3. Access service fabric explorer over HTTPS without certificate errors

In order to create a secure cluster I'll need a valid certificate which will require a custom domain name.

[Create a Service Fabric cluster in Azure using Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm)

> - The certificate must contain a private key.
> - The certificate must be created for key exchange, exportable to a
>     Personal Information Exchange (.pfx) file.
> - The certificate's subject name must match the domain used to access
>     the Service Fabric cluster. This matchng is required to provide SSL
>     for the cluster's HTTPS management endpoints and Service Fabric
>     Explorer. You cannot obtain an SSL certificate from a certificate
>     authority (CA) for the `.cloudapp.azure.com` domain. You must acquire a
>     custom domain name for your cluster. When you request a certificate
>     from a CA, the certificate's subject name must match the custom
>     domain name used for your cluster.

Based on that, would it be correct to assume that I only need one cert and a custom domain to achieve the goals outlined above?

I'd like to follow any best practices on this, so if I'm in error, please provide feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AAD takes care of your client-to-node security, so the only certificate you'll need would be a Server certificate for node-to-node security. This is what they seem to recommend [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security) as well, so you should be on the right track.